# Read MAC addresses from a file and store them as hexadecimal format

Tags: c

I want to read MAC addresses from a file and store them as hexadecimal format. I wrote this part, which can read mac value as character but don't know how to store and convert to hexadecimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  char ch;

    FILE *fp = fopen("/sys/class/net/eth1/address", "r");
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
      printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `%02x` on a number, and `char` is a number.

Comment: In addition to tadman’s comment: Notice that `fgetc` returns an int, not a char. Also check the fopen mode — maybe you want binary?

Comment: @TurePålsson I am not getting it how to store it in a variable as hexadecimal so that I can compare with MAC from other components.

Comment: It is already in hexadecimal format. You might need to strip the `:`s

Comment: @Cheatah can you explain how to do that? I can just print not able to store as well.